# autodetection timeouts in git-credential-manager?

Tags: git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

I just updated to the latest version of Git and now I have these messages on every interaction with remote repositories

[image]

It is supposed to be solved a lot of versions previous to the one I am using, but no.

How can I remove those or avoid pollution?

Comment: Have you looked at the link it shows?

Comment: thanks, double-checking the doc I noticed the typo

Comment: What typo is that?

Comment: my typo, not in the document

Comment: Did that solve the issue? If so, please write an answer explaining clearly what the issue was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a typo in the command `git config --global credential.autoDetectTimeout -1`, now they are gonna

Comment: Maybe you want to set `credential.provider`, for example `git config credential.provider gitlab`. Source: https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#credentialprovider